# parsing string by regular expression

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

There is a method in an old rails application. it can convert a string into an array by regular expression.

Just like this:

```
irb(main):047:0> string = "[(a+50%+1)(b+60%+2)]"
=> "[(a+50%+1)(b+60%+2)]"
irb(main):048:0> string.scan(/\((?<name>\w+)\+(?<percent>\d+)%\+(?<num>\d+)\)/)
=> [["a", "50", "1"], ["b", "60", "2"]]
```

But requirement is changed, I have to add a new value to the string.

I can make it like this:

```
irb(main):049:0> string = "[(a+50%+1+100)(b+60%+2+200)]"
=> "[(a+50%+1+100)(b+60%+2+200)]"
irb(main):050:0> string.scan(/\((?<name>\w+)\+(?<percent>\d+)%\+(?<num>\d+)\+(?<max>\d+)\)/)
=> [["a", "50", "1", "100"], ["b", "60", "2", "200"]]
```

but it can't compatible with the previous,

```
irb(main):051:0> string = "[(a+50%+1)(b+60%+2)]"
=> "[(a+50%+1)(b+60%+2)]"
irb(main):052:0> string.scan(/\((?<name>\w+)\+(?<percent>\d+)%\+(?<num>\d+)\+(?<max>\d+)\)/)
=> []
```

Is there better way to make it? please help, thanks in advance!

Comment: Wow, I didn't know it could work that way. Anyway, why are you not using json or yaml ? sory off topics. Just curious

Comment: This is a old system, I also think json or yaml is better, if I do, I have to rewrite a lot of code, but not enough time.

Comment: Oh okay i thought there is a performance issue or anything. Those legacy code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
((?<name>\w+)\+(?<percent>\d+)%\+(?<num>\d+)(?:\+(?<max>\d+))?
```

make the last groups optional by adding `?` should make it compatible with previous version.

`(?:\+(?<max>\d+))?` is optional so old string match as well.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/sX5xT6/1

Comment: very nice!!! thanks. I think I have to take the time to learn regular expressions.

Comment: @liuzxc your regex is good.Just made the last string optional.